# In a compact metric space, is there an upper bound on the size of a collection of equidistant points?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Fix $\epsilon > 0.$ A finite subset $F\subset X$ of the compact metric space $X$ is called $\epsilon$-**equidistant** if $d(x,y) = \epsilon$ for all distinct $x,y\in X.$

For all $\epsilon>0,$ does there exist $N,$ depending on both $\epsilon$ and $X,$ such that if $F\subset X$ is $\epsilon$-equidistant, then the cardinality of $F$ is at most $N?$

The answer is **yes** for a compact metric group $G$ with identity 1. Let $\mu$ denote the normalized Haar measure of $G$ and $B$ the open ball around 1 with radius $\epsilon/2.$ An upper bound on the size of an $\epsilon$-equidistant set is $1/\mu\big(B).$

But a proof or counterexample for an arbitrary compact metric space eludes me.

Comment: Since this isn't made explicit in your notation, it might be good to say that $N$ is allowed to depend both on $\epsilon$ and on $X$. Also, presumably you mean $d(x, y) = \epsilon$ if $x \neq y$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe I am missing something but it seems like the obvious strategy generalizing your observation for groups works. Consider the open cover of $X$ by open balls of radius $\frac{\epsilon}{2}$. By compactness, this open cover has a finite subcover, say consisting of $N_{\epsilon}$ open balls. Any $\epsilon$-equidistant set of points has the property that each of these open balls contains at most one point, so such a set of points can have size at most $N_{\epsilon}$.

This argument really applies to sets of points satisfying $d(x, y) \ge \varepsilon$ for $x \neq y$.

Comment: You're right. I'm not sure why I convinced myself that total boundedness wouldn't work here.